# HangMan Guess function isn't working as desired

Tags: javascript

My hangman guess function is acting as it shouldn't. It does what it's supposed to as it doesn't decrease when the value of guesses if guessLetter == "", but it goes down when either guessLetter is in secretWord or if it isn't. The issue is at the bottom of my code, in wordGuess() function. Please help if you can thank you. **

> **THIS IS THE LINK TO MY CODEPEN CODE
>    https://codepen.io/MilkyBOii/pen/LyPdRp?editors=0011**

**

```
var guessWords = ["school", "test", "quiz", "pencil", "ruler", "protractor", "teacher", "homework", "science", "math", "english", "history", "language", "elective", "bully", "grades", "recess", ]
var secretWord = guessWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*guessWords.length)];
var wrongLetters = []
var correctLetters = []
var repeatLetters = []
var guesses = Math.round((secretWord.length) + (.5*secretWord.length)) 
function startGame() {
  var testWord = document.getElementById("randTest").innerHTML = secretWord; 
  var correctLettersOUT = "";
    document.getElementById("currentGuess").innerHTML = secretBlanks(secretWord)
    function secretBlanks(secretWord) {
      for (var i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
        correctLettersOUT+=("_ ");
        } return correctLettersOUT;

}}
function correctWord() {
  var guessLetter = document.getElementById("guessLetter").value;
  document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = guessLetter;

 for (var i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
     if (correctLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1)

        if (guessLetter === secretWord[i]) {
          correctLetters.push(guessLetter);
          break;
        }
 }
    if(wrongLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1 && correctLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1) {
         wrongLetters.push(guessLetter);
    }

  /*console.log(correctLetters); **Used to see if the letters were added to the correct array**
  console.log(wrongLetters);*/
wordGuess();
}
function wordGuess() {   
  if(guessLetter.value === ""){
    alert("You didn't guess anything.");
  }else if(guessLetter === secretWord){
    guesses = guesses + 0;
  }else {
    guesses--;
  }   
        console.log(guesses)
}
```

Comment: Could you create a functional stackoverflow code snippet so we can test/check?

Comment: my fault, ill add the link to the actual code

Comment: A functional snippet would be a bit better, since we can edit/run the snippet to test functionality.

Comment: im sorry, still new to the format of StackOverflow so you made just need to deal with my link, sorry for the potential inconvenience.

Comment: i think you need to clarify how your game is supposed to work.  your explanation is confusing and this code doesn't function beyond taking a single letter and logging out how many guesses you've tried.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to decrease `guess` counter in the same `if` block where you add letter to `wrongLetters` array - why checking twice whether word contains letter or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try [my modification to your CodePen](https://codepen.io/Clomp/pen/gWmrGV?editors=0011). I have fixed it so that the guesses count down to 0 & display a game over message.

The problem is in this method (AKA function):

```
function wordGuess() {
    if (guessLetter.value === '') {
        alert("You didn't guess anything.");
    } else if (guesses > 1) {
      // Counts down.
      guesses--;
      console.log('Guesses Left: ' + guesses);

      // Resets the input to a blank value.
      let guessLetter = document.getElementById('guessLetter');
      guessLetter.value = '';
    } else {
      console.log('game over');
    }

    /* You don't want to do this, because it's not decrementing the guesses.
    for (var i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
        if (guessLetter.value === secretWord[i])
            guesses = guesses + 0;
    }
    */
}
```

At the top of the script the guesses variable is being set to the following formula:

```
var guesses = Math.round((secretWord.length) + (.5 * secretWord.length))
```

Which suggests that you want to count down with `guesses--;` instead of count up using `guesses++;` The former works like this: `guesses -= 1;` or `guesses = guesses - 1;` Vice versa for the latter.

Now you can continue to work on your Hangman game! Good luck with it! :)

[JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org) is a handy tool, btw!